# JavaScript how to use array and loop instead of multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I continue to add more `if statements` to this JavaScript snippet to show and hide the image thumbnails. The snippet just hides the thumbnails if the `src` is empty.

I need a way to transform my snippet into array and loop so that I don't have to keep adding on more `if statements` when I add more images in the `div`.

How would I condense my code in a way so that I don't end up with dozens or hundreds of `if statements`?

I have to use JavaScript. jquery is not an option.

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <a href="#img1"><img id="thumb1" src="photo.png"></a>
  <a href="#img2"><img id="thumb2" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img3"><img id="thumb3" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img4"><img id="thumb4" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img5"><img id="thumb5" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img6"><img id="thumb6" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img7"><img id="thumb7" src="picture.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#img8"><img id="thumb8" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img9"><img id="thumb9" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img10"><img id="thumb10" src=""></a>
  <a href="#img11"><img id="thumb11" src="stock.gif"></a>
  <a href="#img12"><img id="thumb12" src=""></a>
</div>

<script>
function checkThumbs() {

var thumb1 = document.getElementById("thumb1"); var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var thumb2 = document.getElementById("thumb2"); var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
var thumb3 = document.getElementById("thumb3"); var img3 = document.getElementById("img3");
var thumb4 = document.getElementById("thumb4"); var img4 = document.getElementById("img4");
var thumb5 = document.getElementById("thumb5"); var img5 = document.getElementById("img5");
var thumb6 = document.getElementById("thumb6"); var img6 = document.getElementById("img6");
var thumb7 = document.getElementById("thumb7"); var img7 = document.getElementById("img7");
var thumb8 = document.getElementById("thumb8"); var img8 = document.getElementById("img8");
var thumb9 = document.getElementById("thumb9"); var img9 = document.getElementById("img9");
var thumb10 = document.getElementById("thumb10"); var img10 = document.getElementById("img10");
var thumb11 = document.getElementById("thumb11"); var img11 = document.getElementById("img11");
var thumb12 = document.getElementById("thumb12"); var img12 = document.getElementById("img12");

  if ((thumb1).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb1.style.display = "none";
      img1.style.display = "none";
      thumb1.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img1.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb2).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb2.style.display = "none";
      img2.style.display = "none";
      thumb2.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img2.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb3).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb3.style.display = "none";
      img3.style.display = "none";
      thumb3.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img3.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb4).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb4.style.display = "none";
      img4.style.display = "none";
      thumb4.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img4.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb5).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb5.style.display = "none";
      img5.style.display = "none";
      thumb5.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img5.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb6).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb6.style.display = "none";
      img6.style.display = "none";
      thumb6.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img6.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb7).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb7.style.display = "none";
      img7.style.display = "none";
      thumb7.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img7.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb8).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb8.style.display = "none";
      img8.style.display = "none";
      thumb8.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img8.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb9).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb9.style.display = "none";
      img9.style.display = "none";
      thumb9.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img9.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb10).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb10.style.display = "none";
      img10.style.display = "none";
      thumb10.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img10.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb11).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb11.style.display = "none";
      img11.style.display = "none";
      thumb11.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img11.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
  if ((thumb12).getAttribute("src") == "") {
      thumb12.style.display = "none";
      img12.style.display = "none";
      thumb12.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img12.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: by the use of jQuery it is very easy

Comment: I have to avoid jQuery in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all the images you will have to use:

```
var allImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbs img');
```

Now you can loop on them to do your logic,

```
for ( var counter = 1; counter <= allImgs.length; counter++)
{
  var thumb = document.getElementById( "thumb" + counter );
  var img = document.getElementById( "img" + counter );
  if ( img && thumb && thumb.getAttribute("src") == "")  //check if the element exists to avoid any run time issues
   {
    thumb.style.display = "none";
    img.style.display = "none";
    thumb.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
    img.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
   }
}
```

this will be dynamic and work for any number of images you have in your div with class `thumbs`.

Comment: the for loop is changed to iterate over all images. Its not copy paste.

Comment: And that statement makes it to work for any number of images.

Comment: this is a good answer but the querySelectorAll is not supported in all browsers. IE9 and down doesn't support it. Firefox 3.5 and down won't work. I'm trying to stick to a method that will work on all browsers.

Comment: IE9 and IE 8 both support it.

Comment: According to this page http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp IE 9 is the first fully supported browser and Firefox 3.5. Anything below IE9 and Firefox 3.5 isn't supported. Can you confirm?

Comment: IE8 is also supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
var thumbParent = document.getElementsById( "thumbs" );
var numberOfThumbs = thumbParent.children;
for ( var counter = 1; counter <= numberOfThumbs ; counter++)
{
   var thumb = document.getElementById( "thumb" + counter );
   var img = document.getElementById( "img" + counter );
   if ( img && thumb && thumb.getAttribute("src") == "")  //check if the element exists to avoid any run time issues
   {
      thumb.style.display = "none";
      img.style.display = "none";
      thumb.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
      img.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What if you add one more image. This will not work then.

Comment: then I would have to set the 12 in the counter to 13. But this method will work in all browsers. the querySelectorAll will not work in IE9 or below.

Comment: @mike you can fetch children() of parent object and get the length of the Array returned

Comment: it works but if I change the class to an id and use getElementbyId instead of getElementsByClassName() it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike `getElementbyId` needs `thumbs` to be an `id` instead of `class` and it won't return an array, just one element. So, it would be `var numberOfThumbs = thumbParents.children;`

Comment: hmm I tried it with `getElementById` and changed the div to and id and changed the var to `numberOfThumbs = thumbParents.children;` but that doesn't seem to work. You said `getElementById` can't return an array?

Comment: @Mike `getElementById` doesn't return an array, it returns only one Element. Can you update the markup in your question if the parent element has an id instead of class?

Comment: ok I updated it in the question to an id for thumbs. I'd rather use id and getElementById because it is supported in all browsers compared to getElementsByClassName.

Comment: for some reason just doesn't work using getElementById with your updated code either. Yes the div is set to id="thumbs"

Comment: @Mike Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: ok I will share a fiddle tomorrow so you can see what is going on. For now I'm using your original code which will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

First finding the length of your child nodes , then looping across the images and then changing the attributes of image having no src.

Here is the JSFiddle File https://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/jv2qL54u/

```
var nodelist = document.getElementById("thumbs").children.length;
for (var images = 0; images <= nodelist; images++) {

  var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[images];
  var src = image.getAttribute("src");
  if (src.length == 0) {
    //write here your logic
    image.style.display = "none";
    image.src = "clearpixeldot.png";
  }
}
```

To remove image flickering you can hide all the images first and show only the images with src. Update here https://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/4w00hsze/.

Comment: this works to hide the thumbs but doesn't hide the large images at the bottom which are defined in `var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");` to `img12`

Answer (score -1):

Please Use Below Script :

```
$(".thumbs").find("a").each(function(){
    var _thiss = $(this);
    var image_obj = $(this).find("img");
  if ($(image_obj).attr("src") == "") {
      var img = $(_thiss).attr("href");
      $(image_obj).css("display","none");
      $(img).css("display","none");
      $(image_obj).attr("src","clearpixeldot.png");
      $(img).attr("src","clearpixeldot.png");
  }
});
```

Comment: Didn't you read it has to be done in javascript and not using jquery ?